# Finding a time stamp within a character string

Tags: python, notepad++

I am writing a timetabling python script in Notepad++ to optimise my workflow. I have data arranged like:

```
2014-07-16_B_019 John Smith -Left(7:00pm)

2014-07-16_B_089 Jack Smith -Late(8:00pm)
```

I wish for a new string for just the time stamp (e.g 7:00pm and 8pm).I did get pretty far using :

```
endNum = editor.getLineEndPosition(editor.lineFromPosition(editor.getCurrentPos())+1) #get position of line final character

stringMe = editor.getTextRange(endNum-7,endNum-1) #Convention must be met!
```

but hard coding a selection range is poor practice, and will break if I have say -Left(11am)

Comment: What can you rely on always being there? The parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Script supports some regular expressions; you can use [`editor.research`](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html#Editor.research) to find the locations of matches for a specified pattern. To find what you're looking for, you could try e.g.

```
r"\((\d{1,2}(?:[:.]\d{1,2})?(?:am|pm)?)\)$"
```

[Demo and explanation at Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rB7iS5/1).

Answer (score 1):

a regular expression is probably going to be the easiest way to extract this information

```
import re
title = "2014-07-16_B_019 John Smith -Left(7:00pm)"
matches = re.search(r"""(\d{4}-  #the year
                         \d{2}-  #the month
                         \d{2})  #the day
                         .*      #anything
                         (\d{1,2}:\d{2})   #Hour:Minute
                         (am|pm)  #am or pm""",title,re.X)
print matches.groups()
```